# Moving charges and magnetic fields: does one effect cause the other?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am a little bit confused about a basic point in electromagnetism, hope someone might help. I know that (1) a moving charge creates a magnetic field around it. I also know that (2) a magnetic field (also that generated by a permanent magnet) affects a moving charge, in the way captured by the formula for the Lorentz force (the magnetic part of it). My question is: how exactly are the two facts related? Does a magnetic field affect a moving charge BECAUSE OF the magnetic field created by the moving charge (that is, (2) BECAUSE OF (1). Or rather are the two facts (1) and (2) to be thought as causally independent? That is, a magnetic field affects a moving charge, but NOT BECAUSE of the magnetic field created by the moving charge.

Comment: Suppose I have a moving charge, and a permanent magnet. The permanent magnet affects the moving charge. But does it affect the moving charge JUST BECAUSE of the magnetic field generated by the moving charge in the first place? Another way to frame the question: if I know the nature of the magnetic field generated by a moving charge, can I also, simply based on this information, know how the moving charge will be affected by the magnetic field created by the permanent magnet? Or not?

Comment: If we know that a dropped rock hit the floor with a certain speed, then we can infer the height from which it was dropped. That doesn't mean the speed with which it hit the floor *caused* it to be dropped from that height. Are you asking a question about what we can deduce from limited information? Or are you asking a question about why electrodynamics requires the influence to go both ways (which is what I originally thought you were asking)?

Comment: Perhaps the question is: is it the magnetic field of the charge which interacts with the magnetic field of the external magnet to produce the force on the charge, or are moving charges affected by an external magnetic field, just by virtue of their motion. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Philip yes is what I am asking. Chiral Anomaly, I guess that I would love to know the answer to both the things you mentioned.